# Why are these DHCP log entries repeated

Tags: logs, dhcp

I see multiple entries from the same device for each attempt to connect. Consider these 3 entries from an iphone and 4 entries from another device. What do the "via ..." indicate ? What does the ":1" mean in "em2:1" ? Why does the IP helper included in some log lines and not others ?

```
Sep 10 10:45:37 btmfdr dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.179 from 98:00:c6:xx:xx:xx (iPhone) via em2
Sep 10 10:45:37 btmfdr dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.179 from 98:00:c6:xx:xx:xx (iPhone) via em1
Sep 10 10:45:37 btmfdr dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.179 from 98:00:c6:xx:xx:xx (iPhone) via 192.168.0.5

Oct  7 07:00:46 btmfdr dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.130 from 54:7f:54:xx:xx:xx (20807049) via em2:1
Oct  7 07:00:46 btmfdr dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.130 from 54:7f:54:xx:xx:xx (20807049) via em2
Oct  7 07:01:30 btmfdr dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.130 from 54:7f:54:xx:xx:xx (20807049) via 192.168.1.5
Oct  7 11:31:32 btmfdr dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.1.130 (192.168.0.17) from 54:7f:54:xx:xx:xx (20807049) via 192.168.1.5
```

Key IPs here are:

- 192.168.0.5 gateway address of master router at head office
- 192.168.1.5 gateway address on same master router for subnet used for a branch office
- 192.168.0.17 non-primary IP on btmfdr, which is the server doing DHCP. (this IP is the listed "IP helper" in the router configs)

Comment: Do you have your DHCP server listen to multiple interfaces?